# How can i have GCD of two numbers from a recursive functions?

Tags: python

Can we have GCD of two numbers from a recursive functions?
Like a and b

```
def recursive_f_gcb(a,b):
```

Comment: What do you mean with *GCB*? Do you mean *GCD*?

Comment: he wants to say gcd:)

Comment: I assume you want to calculate the GCD recursively because you're studying recursion. It's faster & uses less RAM to do it non-recursively. In fact, it's so simple that it's barely worth putting it in a function. ;) And it's already implemented in the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def recursive_f_gcd(a, b):
    if b==0:
        return a
    else:
        return recursive_f_gcd(b, a%b) 
a=18
b=12
print(recursive_f_gcd(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this process :

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if b > a:
        return gcd(b,a)
    r = a%b
    if r == 0:
        return b
    return gcd(r,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter using a `conditional expression`

```
def recursive_f_gcd(a, b):
    return a if not b else recursive_f_gcd(b, a%b)

a = 24
b = 18
print(recursive_f_gcd(a, b))
```

**Output:**

```
6
```